# Which rich:calendar event will be fired by changing a date value in the small preview calendar?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I use a rich:calendar component and my method, which is registered at the attribute "valueChangeListener" is only fire, if a insert a new date manually. But if i used the small preview calendar of this component, nothing will be fired.

With small preview calendar i means something like in this richfaces demo:
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf;jsessionid=5F76DD93066405333AE0F8F7706AE441?c=calendar&tab=usage

I use Richfaces 3.3.*

```
 <rich:calendar id="Date"
    value="#{bean.date}"
    popup="true" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy" enableManualInput="true"
    ajaxSingle="true" buttonIcon="/img/calendar.png"
    immediate="true"
    valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}"
    onchanged="updateDateInSectionA(this.value).text;"
    oninputblur="updateDateInSectionA(this.value).text;" >
    <a4j:support event="onchanged" ajaxSingle="true"
        reRender="section_A"
        actionListener="#{bean.doSomeThingElse}"
        valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}" />
    <a4j:support event="oninputchange" ajaxSingle="true"
        reRender="section_A"
        actionListener="#{bean.doSomeThingElse}"
        valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}" />
    <a4j:support event="oninputkeyup" ajaxSingle="true"
        reRender="section_A"
        actionListener="#{bean.doSomeThingElse}"
        valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}" />
</rich:calendar>
```

The code in valueChangeListener wasn´t executed, but why?

Comment: Don't use `onchanged` attribute and `a4j:support event="onchanged"` in the same `rich:calendar` component. You need use one or second. And answer on your question is **onchanged**.

Comment: Ok i have tried your suggestion, but the code in valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}" wasn´t executed !

Comment: Can you post in comment your updated code?

Comment: <rich:calendar id="Date"
    value="#{bean.date}"
    popup="true" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy" enableManualInput="true"
    ajaxSingle="true" buttonIcon="/img/calendar.png"
    immediate="true"
    valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}"
    onchanged="updateDateInSectionA(this.value).text;"
    oninputblur="updateDateInSectionA(this.value).text;" >   
    <a4j:support event="oninputkeyup" ajaxSingle="true"
        reRender="section_A"
        actionListener="#{bean.doSomeThingElse}"
        valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}" />
</rich:calendar>

Comment: valueChangeListener and change event work together.

Comment: But i have two different logics, which muste be executed. On the on hand "bean.changeDate" and an the other hand java scripts "updateDateInSectionA(this.value).text;". How can i executed these two methods in the rich:calendar component?

Answer (score 0):

i did such a thing and it worked as you said:

```
<rich:calendar id="test" value="#{mybean.date}"> <a4j:support event="onchanged" 
ajaxSingle="true" reRender="xxform" valueChangeListener="#{mybean.date}" />
</rich:calendar>
```