# How to call java script declared methods in a rich:calendar?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have declared the following rich:calendar (i use rich faces 3.3.*):

```
<rich:calendar id="Date"
    value="#{bean.date}"
    popup="true" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy" enableManualInput="true"
    ajaxSingle="true" buttonIcon="/img/calendar.png"
    immediate="true"
    valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}"
    onchanged="updateDateInSectionA(this.value.text);"
    oninputblur="updateDateInSectionA(this.value.text);" >
    <a4j:support event="onchanged" ajaxSingle="true"
       reRender="section_A"
       actionListener="#{bean.doSomeThingElse}"
       valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}" />   
</rich:calendar>
```

I have declared two java script methods on the attributes "onchanged" and "oninputblur". Also it was declared an valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeDate}".

Now i have the problem, that the javascript methods were executed, but not the necessary valueChangeListener method.

If i deleted the two attributes "onchanged" and "oninputblur", the valueChangeListener was executed.

All three methods are important for me. How can i call each three methods?

How can i solve this situation?

// Edit:
The a4j:support tag is also important !

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense: should it say `updateDateInSectionA(this.value.text);`? If so, take care to not return false from the function or stop event propagation in another way.

Comment: you are right, but that isn´t the problem and this doesn´t create the problem too

Comment: If that's a simple typo, please edit your post so others aren't left wondering.

Comment: Instead of `updateDateInSectionA` can't you have a component in section A with a value bound to `#{bean.date}` and rerender it when necessary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which rich:calendar event will be fired by changing a date value in the small preview calendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285781/which-richcalendar-event-will-be-fired-by-changing-a-date-value-in-the-small-pr)